# eBPF program in Android

Tags: android, ebpf, bcc-bpf

How do I compile eBPF program in Android? Do I need to use [adeb](https://github.com/joelagnel/adeb) and bcc to compile the bpf program? I'm very confused from the Android documentation on eBPF [Android documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/bpf). Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Clang included in Android NDK does included target bpf.

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang -print-targets

  Registered Targets:
    ...
    bpf        - BPF (host endian)
    bpfeb      - BPF (big endian)
    bpfel      - BPF (little endian)
    ...
```

You can use `clang --target=bpf ...` to compile your program.